# Draw in multi canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I have problem, I can just draw in first canvas, I can't draw in second, third... canvas?

Can you help me?

```js
App = {};

$(function() {
 setDrawCanvas(0);
 $(document).on('click', '#nav_steps li', function() {
   var $active = $(this).attr('data-n');
   var $canvas = $('#canvas_panel');
   $active -= 1;
   setDrawCanvas($active);

   $('#nav_steps li.active').removeClass('active');
   $(this).addClass('active');
   $canvas.find("canvas").attr("style","display: none;");
   $canvas.find("canvas:eq("+ $active +")").attr("style","display: inline;");


 });
  
}
function getMousePos(canvas, evt) {
 var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
 return {
   x: evt.clientX - rect.left,
   y: evt.clientY - rect.top
 };
}

function fitToContainer(canv){
 canv.width = $('#canvas_panel').width();
 canv.height = $('#canvas_panel').height();
}
function setDrawCanvas(i) {
  $(document).on('DOMNodeInserted', 'canvas:eq('+ i +')', function(e) {
    var canvas = $(this)[0];
    fitToContainer(canvas);
    App.ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    $(document).on('drag dragstart dragend', 'canvas:eq('+ i +')',function(e) {
      var mousePos = getMousePos($(this)[0], e);
      data = {
        x: (mousePos.x), 
        y: (mousePos.y),
        type: e.handleObj.type
      }
      App.draw(data);
    });
  });
}
// Draw Function
App.draw = function(data) {
 App.ctx.strokeStyle = color;
 //App.ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out";//but tay //source-over=default
 App.ctx.lineWidth = linewidth;
 if (data.type == "dragstart") {
  App.ctx.beginPath();
  App.ctx.moveTo(data.x,data.y);
 } else if (data.type == "drag") {
  App.ctx.lineTo(data.x,data.y);
  App.ctx.stroke();
 } else {
  App.ctx.stroke();
  App.ctx.closePath();
 }
}
```

when I click li, console.log is OK, but I can't draw at canvas  2 ,3 ,4 ,5... I just can draw at canvas 1.
Thank

Comment: Why do you have `$(document).on('DOMNodeInserted', 'canvas:eq('+ i +')', function(e) {`? That means it will only run the code inside of it when a given node is inserted into the DOM.

Comment: because i  added "canvas" element with .append in jquery to new file, so in this file i selected "canvas" to draw on it.

Comment: It'd be better if you just setup one handler for when you're dragging on any canvas then use `setDrawCanvas` to pick the right canvas element. Anytime you get an event from another canvas, just ignore it.

Comment: i will try it, Thanks you..